# UIButton image static size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to have default button's image have static size always, and not the frame calculated by `sizeToFit()` somewhere in private API of UIButton.

So, I don't want to resize image itself, and in case my image is `2500x1600`, for example, I want the image to be always `24x24`, so it shouldn't resize the actual button. `button.imageEdgeInsets` doesn't work for me in this case. Also `imageRect` method overriding didn't give correct result, since `contentRect` is already wrong at that point. Also, I **don't want** to use any kind of `resizing image` code. I just want to have native `imageView` have static size.

Is there a way to do that with native `image` property. I'm trying to find solutions, before I finally decide to have custom imageView subView

**Updated:**
It is supposed to not have static width for button. So button's width should depend on the text. But the image size should be static.

Answer (score 1):

try this below line for button,

```
myButton.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

If it does not work the give me some more specific details regarding to your project  How you giving frame to UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

give your button `fix width and fix height` constraints! and it will manage image size as per your button's frame!

You can demonstrate it by just drag and drop one button to your storyboard or xib. set `fixed width, fixed height, top and leading` constraint and set any image to it!

Comment: What if I also need to have button width/height not static? Like I support different languages, and button's width depends on its text. So, as a result, button's width should be something like `contentInset.left + text.width + somePaddingToImage + imageStaticWidth + contentInset.right`

Comment: then also if you will set button's image then it will take size of image that it have!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
button.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

and

```
button.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

after setting the buttons's frame to your desired height and width, you can do this with constraints in interface builder or with your own method in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Added update to my question. I need to have button with dynamic width...

Comment: Then you would need to set the buttons imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets using UIEdgeInsets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
let inset: CGFloat = 10
closeButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: inset, left: inset, bottom: inset, right: inset)
```

You could adjust the width/height of the `imageView` according to edgeInsets.